# Windows Batch String Substitution not working when search string is given by a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wipped up some code that's supposed to delete files that don't have names beginning with the value of `keep`. I'm achieving this by putting the name of the file in `tmpL1` and `tmpL2` while substituting the value of `keep` with nothing. If `tmpL1` and `tmpL2` are different I'm keeping the file, otherwise it gets deleted.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set keep=[File I want to keep]
for /F %%L IN ('dir /b *') do (
    set tmpL1=%%L
    set tmpL2=!tmpL1:%keep%=!
    if !tmpL1!==!tmpL2! (
        echo.[REMOVE]
    ) else (
        echo.[KEEP]
    )
)
```

This is working fine. However, when I put this code in a larger script, setting `tmpL2` suddenly stops working. Instead of (part of) the file name `tmpL2` now literally contains `tmpL1:=`.

Here is the script I want to use it in. The additional `for`-loops are only for going through a directory tree. The main function of the script is still the same.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%G in ('dir /b *-snapshots') do (
    set tmpG1=%%G
    for /F %%H in ('dir /b !tmpG1!\*') do (
        set tmpH1=%%H
        for /F %%I in ('dir /b !tmpG1!\!tmpH1!\*') do (
            set tmpI1=%%I
            for /F %%J in ('dir /b !tmpG1!\!tmpH1!\!tmpI1!\*-SNAPSHOT') do (
                set tmpJ1=%%J
                set tmpJ2=!tmpJ1:~0,8!
                for /F %%K in ('dir /b !tmpG1!\!tmpH1!\!tmpI1!\!tmpJ1!\*!tmpJ2!*.pom /O:N') do (
                    set tmp1=%%K
                )
                set keep=!tmp1:.pom=!
                for /F %%L in ('dir /b !tmpG1!\!tmpH1!\!tmpI1!\!tmpJ1!\*!tmpJ2!*') do (
                    set tmpL1=%%L
                    set tmpL2=!tmpL1:%keep%=!
                    pause
                    if !tmpL1!==!tmpL2! (
                        echo.[REMOVE]
                    ) else (
                        echo.[KEEP]
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I also tried "lazy" delayed expansion by replacing `set tmpL2=!tmpL1:%keep%=!` with `call set tmpL2=%%tmpL1:%keep%=%%`. This also works in the small script, but when I apply it to the big one I get an error like `"=%" can't be syntactically processed in this location` (that's a free translation since my console is in German).

Anyone have an idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to change this line
`set tmpL2=!tmpL1:%keep%=!`

with

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%R in (""!keep!"") do set "tmpL2=!tmpL1:%%~R=!"
```

Comment: Pasted that right in and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
                set tmpL2=!tmpL1:%keep%=!
```

When the `for` loop is parsed, since `keep` is at that time undefined, this will be reduced to

```
                set tmpL2=!tmpL1:=!
```

Comment: Good call! Do you have any idea how I can get around this Problem?

Comment: call is the operative word. Call a subroutine. substitute there (as `tmpL1` and `keep` will then each be defined) and assign to a further variable, then use that further variable as `!var!`

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I created a subroutine with this command: `call set %~3=%%%~1:%~2=%%`. The third parameter then has the value of the first parameter, but nothing is being substituted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
set tmpL2=!tmpL1:%keep%=!
```

write:

```
call :SUB tmpL2 !tmpL1! !keep!
```

then at the bottom of your script, place this:

```
goto :EOF

:SUB return string search [replace]
set "tmpSub=%2"
set "%1=!tmpSub:%3=%4!"
goto :EOF
```